# Containerd overlay permissions flagged as insecure

Tags: linux, docker, container

Is there anyway to remove other permissions in overlay without breaking everything? We are flagged by a security audit due other permissions in /var folder.

Example:

```
/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/629/fs/usr/local/etc/npmrc 5370077 4 -rw-rw-rw 1 root root 31 Jul 2020
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: *are* these permissions insecure? Or are you just getting flagged for something the automated tool doesn't understand?

Comment: I don't know if these permissions are insecure, I checked and it seems normal in few directories. However, I don't know the exact reason of that. If this is the way of containerd snapshotter works then it should be fine, but I need to demonstrate that...

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know why these permissions are detected as "unsafe". Is there a reason for this classification?

Assumption: The permissions are recognized as insecure because "everyone" (in addition to the owner and group, here root:root) has read and write permissions.

Maybe this documentation will help: https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_Docker_v1.3.1_L1_Docker_Linux.audit:414d1855f72c66a847aeee9a3a9ec326

Additional information:
https://jfrog.com/community/devops/linux-permissions-dos-and-donts/

Comment: Your assumption is right, basically they say unless is a dependency you shouldn't use "everyone" permissions in /var. One dollar million question is why this is a dependency in containerd... Containerd socket use the correct permissions, we can discard that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is related with the content of the image deployed, we had the same "issue" with grafana.

Checking its docker file we found (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/Dockerfile):

File:

```
/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/115/fs/etc/grafana/provisioning 28830982 0 drwxrwxrwx 2 472 root 9 Aug 2 04:50
```

Line in docker file:

```
chmod -R 777 "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_HOME/.aws" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING"
```

So basically is the way that the image is created, nothing to do with the runtime. What we see in the snapshots is just the layers of this image.